# react js blueprintjs Date Range Picker not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, daterangepicker, gettime

I need create DateRangePicker on BlueprintJS([documentation](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/v1/#datetime/daterangepicker)) and RangePicker in my component,
like in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv2Xi.png).

I instalation all npm packages, and do all by instructions:

```
import { DateRangePicker } from "@blueprintjs/datetime";

<DateRangePicker
    value={[this.state.startDate, this.state.endDate]}
    onChange={this.handleDateChange}
/>
```

but anyway have error:

```
Cannot read property 'startDate' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'startDate' of null
```

please, help, what i need for working DateRangePicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define `state` as field of your component. By default, if `state` is not set, it equals to `null`

```
import React from 'react'
import { DateRangePicker } from "@blueprintjs/datetime";

class MyAwesomeComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            startDate: new Date("2018-05-01T12:13:30.643Z"),
            endDate: new Date("2018-05-03T12:13:30.643Z")
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="my-component">
                <DateRangePicker
                    value={[this.state.startDate, this.state.endDate]}
                    onChange={this.handleDateChange}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I already did, it does not work.

[error screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/BE8CDkx.png)

Comment: @LiorBraginsky this is an another error, different from question. Probably, you pass parameter of wrong type. I suppose, ```this.state.startDate``` and ```this.state.endDate``` should be instatnces of ```Date```.

Comment: @LiorBraginsky I'm not familiar with Blueprint components, so to solve other errors you should browse documentation and check what types of params you should pass. The main problem is corresponding to React, so it is already solved :)

Comment: the problem is not solved:( I still can not make it so that I would get the date :(

Comment: @LiorBraginsky I just modified my answer, try this (I have changed the ```this.state = {...}``` section)